# Como juntar observações de tabelas que possuem um conjunto diferente de variáveis em R?

Tags: r, data.frame

No caso abaixo id corresponde a observações contidas em dois data frames diferentes, sendo que no df1 as observações possuem a variável x e no df2 as observações possuem x e z

Nesses casos como juntar os dois data frames? O conmando `rbind` não funciona

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=11:20, x = rnorm(10),z=rnorm(10))

dados <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

O ideal é que a coluna não presente em todos os data frames seja adicionada, atribuindo o valor NA para as observações que não possuem essa variável.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso uso sempre a função `bind_rows` do `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- bind_rows(df1,df2)

> dados
Source: local data frame [20 x 3]

      id          z           x
   (int)      (dbl)       (dbl)
1      1  0.8179472          NA
2      2  0.2624969          NA
3      3 -0.1684590          NA
4      4 -0.1239140          NA
5      5  0.4434778          NA
6      6 -0.8865578          NA
7      7  0.1160360          NA
8      8  0.5604733          NA
9      9 -2.2761215          NA
10    10 -0.7920775          NA
11    11  1.7650167 -1.38172797
12    12 -1.0004357  2.64345620
13    13 -1.6467084 -0.01361806
14    14  0.9055755  2.00354819
15    15 -0.1645952  0.57657614
16    16  0.2675339 -0.01727064
17    17  0.6383209 -0.43920834
18    18 -1.4729775 -0.35907320
19    19  0.9345417 -0.93673279
20    20 -0.7888048  0.36903134
```

---

Achei legal colocar aqui uma comparação de tempo de execução de todas alternativas:

```
> microbenchmark(
+   base = merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE),
+   dplyr = dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2),
+   data.table = data.table::rbindlist(list(df1,df2), fill = TRUE),
+   plyr = plyr::rbind.fill(df1,df2)  
+ )
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
       base 1370.788 1578.6680 2138.9646 1852.2805 2296.0775   8607.060   100
      dplyr   64.768  111.1450  205.0742  126.2580  161.3900   4055.948   100
 data.table  173.051  239.8905 2860.8464  280.5705  352.7535 253411.277   100
       plyr  362.365  440.6795  597.4301  506.5200  622.8745   4323.416   100
```

Note que a solução usando `dplyr` é a mais rápida de todas. Mais de 10x mais do que o `base` e cerca 2x mais rápida do que a solução por `data.table`. Estou comparando as medianas!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `rbind.fill` do package `plyr` para fazer o que você quer:

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=11:20, x = rnorm(10),z=rnorm(10))

dados <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode usar a função `rbindlist` do pacote `data.table`, com a opção `fill = TRUE`:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1,df2), fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução do próprio pacote base é utilizar o `merge`. Apesar de ser normalmente utilizado para fazer o *match* entre colunas, também funciona como um *rbind* com *fill* contanto que você dê os argumentos corretos. É uma boa opção, especialmente se o uso do outro pacote (`dplyr`, `data.table`, `plyr`) for apenas este.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
> df2 <- data.frame(id=11:20, x = rnorm(10),z=rnorm(10))
> merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
   id           z            x
1   1  0.55248779           NA
2   2  0.18582807           NA
3   3  0.15226974           NA
4   4 -1.01512686           NA
5   5 -0.13544547           NA
6   6  0.07923429           NA
7   7  0.13807574           NA
8   8  0.08524223           NA
9   9  1.28002174           NA
10 10  0.46765903           NA
11 11 -0.46550011  0.083700363
12 12  0.02691267  0.623578122
13 13  1.60678489 -1.043026698
14 14 -1.77340124  0.001289941
15 15  0.89638862  1.388973550
16 16  0.47108478  0.047770795
17 17 -0.08128863 -0.099346609
18 18  0.24915884 -1.423919181
19 19  0.75685907  1.822885566
20 20  0.48232639 -1.172792347
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite,

Usando o pacote magrittr ao tentar empilhar 3 datasets usando o comando abaixo a seguir:

dataset <- dat1%>%merge(dat2)%>%merge(dat3)
dataset

e tambem tentando reduce, rbind, merge, join_all, o R junta os datasets, mas sem obs, sempre vem com 0 obs. e 13 variáveis, alguém pode ajudar? Os 3 data sets tem as mesmas colunas e há um padrão no nome.